# Can The Zeta Project be understood enough individually?

Tags: dc-animated-universe, the-zeta-project

I am considering to watch The Zeta Project from the DCAU but I don't know much about it and I didn't watch many episodes from Batman Beyond (including Zeta ones). So can I enjoy it individually or should I look back to some other DCAU stuff before it for better understanding?

Comment: Pretty much stand alone  "Wrongly accused on the run to clear their name"  set "ten minutes into the future". You'll be fine. Like most single character comic or comic basic series, you don't need much if any background, it will all be provided.

Comment: @cde if you know enough, you can covert it into answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [cde](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/23541/cde) puts it, you can watch [The Zeta Project](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/The_Zeta_Project) without having watched all the [Batman Beyond](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Beyond) episodes.
It's mainly because it is a spin-off series based on the character [Zeta](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Zeta_(DCAU)) from the Batman Beyond episode named [ZETA](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Zeta_(episode)) season 2, ep 20.

Thus, to answer your question, **you should start watching it** as it's remarkably interesting (in my opinion). But, there are a few cross-over episodes like [Shadows](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Shadows) which might have Batman Beyond as its pre-requisites:

> Batman (Terry) and Bruce view security footage of a mall's destruction and based on the incomplete footage, they believe Zeta to be responsible.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).